# Can I force the install of a package that requires a newer Python version than the one I have installed?

Tags: python, pip

I know it isn't a correct thing to do, but I would like to try to install package that requires Python 3.8, but my installed Python is 3.7.

Is it possible using pip? Or I must clone the repository and change the `setup.py`?

Comment: `pip install --help` → `--python-version <python_version>` may help.

Comment: There's probably a reason it requires that specific version of Python. You may get some unpleasant surprises if you force the installation anyway.

Comment: Right, it's not common for maintainers to add this metadata just for the heck of it. That usually means something is broken on 3.7. Python 3.7 is a [few months from EOL anyway](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) so update your Python version..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--ignore-requires-python` option.

```bash
pip install --help
```

```
  --ignore-requires-python    Ignore the Requires-Python information.
```

You can try it with your package, or also with this minimal `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="foobar",
    version="1.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires="<3.7"
)
```

With Python 3.7,

```
$ pip install .
Processing /home/vvvvv/75726452
ERROR: Package 'foobar' requires a different Python: 3.7.11 not in '<3.7'

$ pip install . --ignore-requires-python
Processing /home/vvvvv/75726452
Installing collected packages: foobar
    Running setup.py install for foobar ... done
Successfully installed foobar-1.0
```

---

However, as [Mark Ransom suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726452/can-i-force-the-install-of-a-package-that-requires-a-newer-python-version-than-t/75726684#comment133589251_75726452), there probably is a good reason the package you are trying to install does requires a version of Python different from 3.7.